# CLLocation course property always invalid

Tags: ios

I've been using `CLLocationManager` alot these days with mixed results. I'm able to get locations from the GPS and also significant location changes when the app is running in the background.

However, I always seem to get a course of -1.0, which (according to the documentation) indicates an invalid course.

In my `didUpdateToLocation` method I'm simply doing the following:

```
double courseDegrees = newLocation.course;
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT: Yes, I've tried it while moving.**

Comment: What is the course when you are using the ios simualtor, with GPS simualtion ?

Comment: Further can you show the relevant part of your didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation method ?

Comment: I have not tried this on the simulator, only on my device. The only relevant code I can think of from that method is what I pasted above. I can get altitude with no problems by saying newLocation.altitude, same with horizontal and vertical accuracy. It's just course that's the problem.

Comment: Aha!, probably the significant location change is the cause, try to change to normal mode.

Comment: Normal as in startUpdatingLocation ??? I've tried that as well, same result.

Comment: Normal is AccuracyBest, or AccuracyBestForNavigation

Comment: I use AccuracyBestForNavigation

Answer (score 3):

From the docu of CLLocationManager Class Reference:

> startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
>
> This interface delivers new events only when it detects changes to the
>   device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less frequent updates
>   and significantly lower power usage.

To receive a course you need GPS, and not cell tower locating. If you need course then you 
have to change to use `startUpdatingLocation` start using

```
desiredAccuracy= AccuracyBestForNavigation
```

Comment: Even when I am moving it gives me a -1.0 value.

Comment: which device, which IOS version?

Comment: I have an iPhone with iOS 6.0 (10A403)

Comment: First please check using the simulator, if it works in simulator then Measure the value of location.horicontalAccuracy what does it give. (Do you have good GPS sitaution with free open sky?)

Comment: When I test I usually take a walk around the block, every new location I get is stored on my server. I've had accuracy as bad as 1414.0 when indoors up to 30.0 outdoors. I will try it on simulator.

Comment: The simulator gave me a horizontal accuracy of 75.0 and a course of -1.0

Comment: OK, found the cause in the docu, a bit hidden

Comment: Yes 75 is usually not GPS, GPS has 5-10, so now all is clear it is the significant loc change

Comment: I went for another walk and this time it worked. I haven't changes anything in my code. Thanks for your help and sorry to waste your time.

Comment: ok, but for my interest: as it worked: was it now in significat loc mode, or startUpdatingLocation mode?

Comment: It was in startUpdatingLocation mode.

Comment: Ok, so my answer is correct, you frist have been in significant chanegs mode, which does not give you course, neither in simualto nor real, now in startUpdating location it works.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that `AccuracyBestForNavigation` is required to enable the course value? I have not been able to find any statement to that effect in the docs.